# Не дает сделать merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Сделал новую ветку и сделал `merge`, после чего добавил исправленный после конфликта файл и пишу `git commit` и тут такое:

[image: git_bash]

```
Merge branch 'branch'

# Conflicts:
#       myfile.txt
#
# It looks like you may be committing a merge.
# If this is not correct, please remove the file
#       .git/MERGE_HEAD
# and try again.

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#
# Changes to be commited:
#   modified:   myfile.txt
#
```

что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как я понял, при попытке слияния у вас возник конфликт. вы его устранили и командой *commit* повторяете попытку слияния.

при этом запустился редактор *vim* для редактирования сообщение о слиянии. сразу предложен и обычно вполне подходящий вариант — в первой строке.

после сохранения файла (<kbd>:wq</kbd>, затем <kbd>enter</kbd>) пустые и закомментированные строки будут отброшены. в них — всего лишь подсказки для вас.

---

**дополнение**

если вы всё-таки хотите отказаться от этого коммита, удалите все непустые и незакомментированные строки (в приведённом случае — одна первая строка), для чего переместите «курсор» (например, с помощью стрелок вверх/вниз) на удаляемую строку и нажмите <kbd>dd</kbd>. а потом сохраните файл, как написано выше. *commit* не будет создан.